# Run Hortonworks Apache Phoenix sqlline.py with nohup and input file even through errors

Tags: bash, hadoop, nohup, sqlline

I want to run a sql script filled with upsert lines (around 20k of them) with Hortonworks sqlline.py.
I also want to do it using nohup, because it might take a while (given my system's resource constraints).
It would be great if I could also time the execution with bash's time utility.

What I tried:

```
$ nohup bash -c '/path/to/sqlline.py /path/to/file.sql' > ~/outputfile.txt
```

It works, until it finds the first `upsert` instruction that fails.
The error I get is this:

```
Aborting command set because "force" is false and command failed: <failed upsert line here>
```

If I try to time it, the command line looks like this:

```
$nohup bash -c 'time /path/to/sqlline.py /path/to/file.sql' > ~/outputfile.txt'
```

But I'll still get an error and subsequent abortion on the first bad `upsert`.

How can I set the "force" parameter in sqlline.py?

Comment: I don't know the first thing about sqlline.py, but you could try `/path/to/sqlline.py --help`.

Comment: it doesn't work, as sqlline.py understands '-- help' as a connection parameter and gives off an connection error